# Who wins when everyone takes lethal damage simultaneously?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-multiplayer

I am building an edh deck for about 5 dollars and was wondering,
If I cast [Sickening Dreams](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sickening%20Dreams) dealing more than enough damage to kill my opponent and I at the same time, who wins?

Answer (score 9):

It's a draw. Whenever all remaining players lose at the same time, the game ends in a draw.

From the [Basic Rulebook](https://www.wizards.com/magic/rules/en_mtgm11_rulebook_lr_web.pdf), under "Winning the Game:

> If both players would lose the game at the same time, the
>   game is a draw—nobody wins.

Similar information is repeated under the glossary for "Life total" and "draw the game".

Answer (score 1):

The game is a draw. MTG's rules are not designed to try to prevent draws. This is perhaps most evidenced by the card [Divine Intervention](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Divine%20Intervention) which can specifically cause the game to end in a draw.

Comment: Note if you want to link to a Magic card you can use [mtg:Card Name], also if you make an edit to your answer just make the edit, don't point out that you changed something.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the pointer on [mtg:Card Name]. This was my first post in this exchange and I wasn't sure of the style preferences here. I know some places prefer people to make obvious edits after initial post.